# why shape can not be appied to the textview in android

Tags: java, android, textview

I am new to Android, and I have got this problem : the shape drawable cannot be applied to the TextView.
The java code in my textview as below:

```
shape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_tag_round_corner);
this.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
this.setBackgroundColor(color);
this.setText(roleName);
this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

XML shape :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="5dp"></corners>
<padding
    android:left="5dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
/>
</shape>
```

Finally, the TextView does not get the shape and the color setted in the code, why?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one drawable as the background.

First you set the shape (which is transparent), and then replace it with the color.

If you want a colored shape, use that xml :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

  <corners android:radius="5dp"></corners>
  <padding
    android:left="5dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
/>
</shape>
```

And then :

```
shape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_tag_round_corner);
shape.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP ));
this.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
```

Comment: that's right,actually I want to change color every time,so how to make it,thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer. (You still need to specify a color other than transparent for the shape)

Comment: I have tried several times with different types of PorterDuff.Mode,howerver it did not work.The color is always dismissed.finally,I make different xml files to achieve the goal.Thank you for giving these suggest and helping me improve my edits,you are so cool!

Comment: @StephaneMathis.just test this function,do not mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can have shapes for textviews in android, go to your xml file and look for the intial lines of code
 they would look something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ScreenOnOff" >
```

Here the relative layout is a type of drawable view, and try to **gravity** in xml file not through java. Your drawable problem will be solved in xml itself. Hope this was of some help